# Doxygen Output Format for SharePoint

Tags: php, sharepoint, documentation, doxygen

I have a project in PHP documented with the Doxygen tool (very pleased with that one), and i would like to integrate all the documentation (currently an HTML site) into my company's SharePoint installation.

How would i go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a bunch of HTML files right? So can't you upload to a document library, either individually or as part of a ZIP archive?

Comment: is there any specific format i need to follow in the Doxygen configurations? i am not that knowledgable in sharepoint so i am trying to figure out what i am doing wrong

Comment: ok got it - i was uploading to the wrong directory